# Getting rid of the encoding in lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to print a XML file using lxml and Python.

Here is the code:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.Element('root')
>>> child = etree.SubElement(root, 'child')
>>> print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding = None)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<root>
  <child/>
</root>
```

As you can see, I have declared `encoding = None`, however it still shows `encoding = 'ASCII'` in the final output. Which I guess is expected. If I don't put in the `encoding` tag, it still shows ASCII.

Is there any way I can just get the XML version tag and not the encoding part? I want the output to be like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It shouldn't matter what lxml.etree outputs as long as it's valid XML. If you really want to, you can glue strings together:

```
'<?xml version="1.0"?>\n' + etree.tostring(root, pretty_print = True, encoding = 'ASCII')
```

It's unclear why you want to remove it, since ultimately XML needs to know what charset it's in to make sense of anything. The [XML 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing) includes a method of guessing charsets, and seems to encourage the use of encoding declarations:

> In the absence of [external information], it is a fatal error ... for an entity which begins with neither a Byte Order Mark nor an encoding declaration to use an encoding other than UTF-8.
>
> ...
>
> Unless an encoding is determined by a higher-level protocol, it is also a fatal error if an XML entity contains no encoding declaration and its content is not legal UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: Uhm ok. I will look over it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Wasn't really helpful in answering the question